# Can I repeat DLC maps?

Tags: fire-emblem-awakening

I've been thinking about picking up some of the DLC packs, and I was wondering if the DLC is repeatable or whether it's restricted to one run per save file. For example, I do an early run of the easy EXP map/battle/thing. Can I do another run later in the game when I pick up some new units?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yup, all DLC maps can be replayed as often as you like.

Likewise, Spotpass teams may be summoned and fought as many times as desired.

Comment: The game even keeps track of your record number of turns for a DLC map so that you can challenge yourself to do better.

Comment: Repeating DLC missions is great for acquiring multiple copies of DLC skill or class-change items. Also, the missions in the Golden Pack are meant to be repeated to obtain gold, experience, or rare weapons.